# Сгенерировать диапазон часов для datetimepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery

Использую популярный плагин datetimepicker для выбора даты и времени. 
В нем есть метод allowTimes, где указываются разрешенные к выбору часы, к примеру:

```
jQuery(".datetimepicker").datetimepicker({
    timepicker: true,
    allowTimes: [
        '12:00', '12:30', '13:00'
    ]
});
```

Как реализовать автоматом список разрешенных к выбору часов из указанного пользователем диапазона, к примеру 12:30 - 14:00 – где массив, будет следующим `['12:30', '13:00', '13:30', '14:00']`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используя библиотеку [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) можно так. Сама функция [add( )](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/).

```js
var timeStart = '12:30';
var timeEnd = '14:00';

var allowTimes = [];
while (timeStart !== timeEnd) {
  allowTimes.push(timeStart);

  timeStart = moment(timeStart, 'HH:mm').add(30,      'm').format('HH:mm');
}
allowTimes.push(timeEnd);
    
console.log(allowTimes);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/moment@2.20.1/moment.js"></script>
```

Comment: Не нужно добавить код в сниппет если он не рабочий.

Answer (score 2):

Не знаю какую версию вы использовали? Или что то еще, но вот посмотрите здесь. Все именно так как вы хотели.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".datetimepicker").datetimepicker({
      timepicker: true,
      allowTimes: [
          '12:00', '12:30', '13:00','13:30','14:00',
'14:30', '15:00', '15:30', '16:00',   ]
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.16/jquery.datetimepicker.full.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.16/jquery.datetimepicker.css">
<input type="text" class="datetimepicker" />
```